# Не получается присоединиться к рабочему процессу в gdb

Tags: gdb

вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

        int i{};
        std::cout<<"pid = "<<getpid()<<std::endl;
        while(1)
        {
                sleep(1);
                std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

компилирую вот так: `g++ -Wall -g3 -O0 main2.cpp -o qq`
Запускаю программу и пытаюсь присоединиться к работающей программе через gdb с помощью строки `gdb -p 9073`. Вот что выдаёт:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 9241
Reading symbols from /home/ivan/first/qq...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so...
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so...
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1)
0x00007f29f9c8d334 in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=<optimized out>, clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=req@entry=0x7ffd35a33510, rem=rem@entry=0x7ffd35a33510)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
78  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

если пытаюсь присоединиться с помощью `gdb /путь/к/файлу 9073` или `(gdb) attach 9073`, то показывает то же самое

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo gdb -p PID`

Comment: пробовал. не помогает. показывает тоже самое

Comment: Я тоже  пробовал. Например, если вы наберете в этом месте `where`, то что говорит gdb?

Comment: (gdb) where
#0  0x00007ff31992c334 in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=<optimized out>, clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=req@entry=0x7ffcbd805360, rem=rem@entry=0x7ffcbd805360)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
#1  0x00007ff319932047 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0x7ffcbd805360, remaining=remaining@entry=0x7ffcbd805360) at nanosleep.c:27
#2  0x00007ff319931f7e in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/posix/sleep.c:55
#3  0x000055753b00a267 in main () at main2.cpp:14
(gdb)

Comment: Значит вы успешно приаттачились. Сейчас в недрах `sleep(1);`. Понятно, что этих сорсов нет. Можете повводить `n` (next) и через некоторое число шагов окажетесь в main в строке 15 -- `std::cout<<i<<std::endl;`

Comment: то есть дело в `sleep`? просто если я поменяю программу на ту, которая просто бесконечно выводи слово hello(без `sleep`), то у меня не только остается эта проблема, но еще и постоянное нажатие `n` ни к чему не приводит. Да и я начал изучать gdb по туториалу на youtube и там у человека точно такая же программа со `sleep`, но у него не выводиться никаких надписей по типу `No debugging symbols found` и для того, чтобы нормально начать отладку, ему не приходится много раз вводить `n`

Comment: Если вы только начинаете изучать gdb, то проще всего не аттачиться к уже запущенной программе (я, если честно, даже не помню всех тонкостей такой отладки), а запускать ее под отладчиком. У вас -- `gdb ./qq`. Потом, на промпт gdb вводите -- `br main` (или где хотите остановиться для отладки), потом запускаете программу -- `r`. И далее отлаживаетесь с точки остановки

Comment: Кстати, вместо youtube, может лучше почитать GNU-сное руководство? (традиционно, у них хорошая документация)